# g:include not working in _header.gsp

Tags: grails

I am maintaining a grails 1.1.1 application. There is an include code which works if we include from a regular gsp. But when I try to include it from _header.gsp it doesn't work. I am using exactly the same  statement. It actually calls the method in the controller but nothing gets returned in the view.
Following is the code which works from a regular gsp

```
    <g:include controller="abcGenericComponent" action="visitOurBoardsComponent" />
```

This is the method in controller

```
def visitOurBoardsComponent = {
    def visitOurBoardsContent = abcGenericComponentService.getVisitOurBoardsComponent(request)
    log.debug "Calling vistitboards ${visitOurBoardsContent}"
    [visitOurBoardsContent: visitOurBoardsContent]
}
```

The log statement is showing up in the logs. That means the method is getting executed.

This is the included gsp

```
<ul>
<g:each var="ourBoards"
        in="${visitOurBoardsContent}">


    <li>

        <a href="${ourBoards?.url}">${ourBoards?.displayName} </a>

    </li>

</g:each>
```